# Why does the container lose 10px height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which is basically a container that has a width and is then filled up with squares so there is an equal number of squares accorss and down:

```js
var container = $('.container'),
    numberOfSquares = 25,
    squareSize = container.width() / numberOfSquares;

for (var squares = 0; squares < numberOfSquares * numberOfSquares; squares++) {
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo(container);
}

$('.gridSquare').css({
    "height": squareSize + "px",
    "width": squareSize + "px"
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 960px;
}
.gridSquare {
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

My question is why does the `.container` lose 10px in height (if you inspect element it is only 950px high), even though the squares inside are square, there is an equal number vertically and horizontally and the row fills up the full 960px?

I've just checked and this only seems to occur in chrome

Comment: `display: inline-block` does strange things. Try testing with `overflow: hidden` on `.container` and `float: left` on `.gridSquare` (it's 950.391px).

Comment: works fine in firefox, seems browser related

Comment: Squaresize is not (always) a round number. You can use Math.round(), Math.floor() or Math.ceil().

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, I thought it may be about inline-block so I tried float left with a clear on block elements but still the same effect in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/5ojjbwms/8/

Comment: @HenriS but if it fits perfectly horizontally (full 960px) and I use the same measurement for the width and the height, then why isn't the height also taking full 960px?

Comment: You have a `height: 960px;` property defined on `.container` in that fiddle, of course it's 960px.

Comment: @Pete, see the voted answer. Exactly wat I mean with rounded number.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv sorry, remove the height and you see it reverts to having the same problem of being 950px so it isn't the inline-block that is causing the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you can only draw at full pixels. The height of each square is rounded from 38.4px down to 38px. 25 * 38px = 950px.

Comment: ah okay, but why wouldn't I get a 10px space on my horizontal row then?

Comment: You have a css rule which sets the width to 960px no matter what. The squares however only take 950px of the width. Or the browser might actually make them fit to the css width.

Comment: why does that rounded? I don't see OP using any round method.

Comment: If that were true then you would see grey on the right side of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ojjbwms/10/ (I have put a background-color on the container), but the black squares fill the row fully

Comment: But it does seem to be an issue with chrome's rendering of partial pixels for height

Comment: @Pete Chrome truncates the pixels. See http://jsfiddle.net/mshjbqvn/ and http://jsfiddle.net/mshjbqvn/1/